# Python & ActiveSync file exchange

Tags: python, python-3.x, activesync

I have the following problem: 
I want to copy some files with a python3 script from a (windows) mobile device which is connected via ActiveSync to a windows computer.

I tried it like that, showing the 3 failed Path-trys:

```
def CopyDir(LocDir, DestDir):
    shutil.copytree(LocDir, DestDir)

Dir = '%%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%%\MD_Data' # Path worked in .bat - but not here
Dir = 'Computer\Pocket_PC\\\Program Files' # Direct path out of windows explorer - didn't work
Dir = '::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\activesyncwpdenumerator#umb#2&306b293b&0&activesyncwpddevice-ab5f2fe4-d830-f1e7-d806-33298de2d8ee-#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\f%7CS%7C%5C\f%7CF%7C%5CProgram%20Files%5C' # Cryptic path read out by a windows clipboard tool - didn't work

CopyDir(Dir, DestDir+'\\MD_Data')
```

The error is always the same: system couldn't find path

Now I'm asking myself, do I simply use the wrong path format for ActiveSync? Or do I need any special ActivSync modul? (Didn't find one)

Thanks already in advance!